# How to get the right selectedIndex when multiple select elements are on the same page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do I maintain the correct HTMLSelectElement.selectedIndex while I have multiple select element in a loop with no IDs?

I am loading dynamic forms on a webpage, which contains a select element with a list of priority. Each priority has a different color as an option and when selected the same color/Css class should be applied to the select element.
It is possible to add many of those form, therefore there is multiple select element with the same list of priority on the page.

The following JS function works to apply style to the option but it doesn't work to apply the style to the select element once there are more than on eon the page.

The problem comes from the selectedIndex always returning the selected index of the last element on the page.

How can I fix this?

```
function ddlColoring(high,medium,low,psar)
{

    var selectArray = document.getElementsByClassName('ac-priority');

    for (var t = 0; t < selectArray.length; t++) {
        var select = selectArray[t];

        for (var i = 0; i < select.options.length; i++) {

            if (select.options[i].value === high) {
                select.options[i].className = "lbl-action-priority-high";

                if (i == select.selectedIndex) {
                    select.className = "lbl-action-priority-high ac-priority";
                }
            }
            else if (select.options[i].value === medium) {
                select.options[i].className = "lbl-action-priority-medium";
                if (i == select.selectedIndex) {
                    select.className = "lbl-action-priority-medium ac-priority";
                }
            }
            else if (select.options[i].value === low) {
                select.options[i].className = "lbl-action-priority-low";
                if (i == select.selectedIndex) {
                    select.className = "lbl-action-priority-low ac-priority";
                }
            }
            else if (select.options[i].value === psar) {
                select.options[i].className = "lbl-action-priority-psar";
                if (i == select.selectedIndex) {
                    select.className = "lbl-action-priority-psar ac-priority";
                }
            }
            else {
                select.options[i].className = "";
            }


            select.onchange = function () {

                for (var j = 0; j < select.options.length; j++) {

                    if (j == select.selectedIndex) {

                        if (select.options[j].value === high) {
                            select.className = "lbl-action-priority-high ac-priority";
                        }
                        else if (select.options[j].value === medium) {

                            select.className = "lbl-action-priority-medium ac-priority";
                        }
                        else if (select.options[j].value === low) {

                            select.className = "lbl-action-priority-low ac-priority";
                        }
                        else if (select.options[j].value === psar) {

                            select.className = "lbl-action-priority-psar ac-priority";
                        }
                        else {
                            select.className = "";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to listen to the event changing and reflect that change someway on the select element to be able to style it accordingly. Below is one suggestion. I used jQuery since you tagged your question with it.

```js
$('.priority-select').on('change', function() {
  var $el = $(this);
  var selectedPriority = $el.val();
  $el.attr('data-priority', selectedPriority);
});
```

```css
.priority-select {
  border: 3px solid;
}

.priority-select[data-priority="high"] {
  border-color: red;
}

.priority-select[data-priority="medium"] {
  border-color: orange;
}

.priority-select[data-priority="low"] {
  border-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="priority-select">
  <option value="">Select a Priority</option>
  <option value="high">high</option>
  <option value="low">low</option>
  <option value="medium">medium</option>
</select>

<select class="priority-select">
  <option value="">Select a Priority</option>
  <option value="high">high</option>
  <option value="low">low</option>
  <option value="medium">medium</option>
</select>

<select class="priority-select">
  <option value="">Select a Priority</option>
  <option value="high">high</option>
  <option value="low">low</option>
  <option value="medium">medium</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks, nice solution